# cakephp query builder not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query

```
$p = $this->Products
  ->findById($id)
->select(['name'])
  ->contain(['Categories.Sizes' => function($q) {
         return $q->select(['id', 'name']); 
    } 
  ]);
```

which is only returning product's name and not the Size of the product's category. But if the remove the `select` function which accepts the field names then it delivers also the Sizes

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: what are you hoping is returned?

Comment: select id, name, category_id

Answer (score 1):

According to the CakePHP 3 book, in the area "[Selecting Rows From A Table](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table)", you can specify which fields you want returned by including them in a `select` array:

```
$query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name']) // <-- Notice this line
    ->where(['id !=' => 1])
    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']);
```

So for yours, you're limiting the fields that are returned because you're specifying that you only want the 'name' field.